# In Pandas, how to get the fraction of occurrences in a level of a multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns, `Type` and `Time`:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'Time' : ['9:11', '9:54', '15:12', '11:39', '21:50', '15:40', '1:23', '1:48', '9:13', '9:48']})
```

`Type` refers to certain categorized events (here, `foo` and `bar`), and `Time` is  a string representing the time of day. I would like to determine in which hour of the day the highest *proportion* of `foo` occurs.

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
def get_hour(timestring):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(timestring).hour

df['_hour'] = df['Time'].apply(get_hour)
grouped_count = df.groupby(['_hour', 'Type']).count()
print(grouped_count)
```

which prints

```
            Time
_hour Type      
1     foo      2
9     bar      1
      foo      3
11    bar      1
15    bar      1
      foo      1
21    foo      1
```

Here the `Time` column represents the total number of occurrences of each type for each hour. However, I'd like to generate an auxiliary column, say `Fraction`, which has the fraction of each occurrence with that hour, like this:

```
            Time   Fraction
_hour Type      
1     foo      2   1.0
9     bar      1   0.25
      foo      3   0.75
11    bar      1   1.0
15    bar      1   0.5
      foo      1   0.5
21    foo      1   1.0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the *_hour* index and use `transform` (or `apply`) to calculate the *fraction*:

```
grouped_count['Fraction'] = grouped_count.groupby(level='_hour').Time.transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

grouped_count
#            Time  Fraction
#_hour Type                
#1     foo      2      1.00
#9     bar      1      0.25
#      foo      3      0.75
#11    bar      1      1.00
#15    bar      1      0.50
#      foo      1      0.50
#21    foo      1      1.00
```

---

If you don't need *Time* column, you can also do `.value_counts(normalize=True)`:

```
df.groupby('_hour').Type.value_counts(normalize=True)
#_hour  Type
#1      foo     1.00
#9      foo     0.75
#       bar     0.25
#11     bar     1.00
#15     bar     0.50
#       foo     0.50
#21     foo     1.00
#Name: Type, dtype: float64
```

with a standard `h:m` string, you can also parse the `hour` as follows:

```
df.groupby(df.Time.str.extract(r'^(\d+)', expand=False)).Type.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: Or, `= grouped_count.div(grouped_count.groupby(level='_hour').sum())`

Comment: Indeed what I actually preferred was to calculate the normalized value counts (and extract their maximum) without creating auxiliary columns. (I finally used `df.groupby(df.Time.apply(get_hour)).Type.value_counts(normalize=True)` because I find the `get_hour` method somewhat easier to understand than string parsing / regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#get hour by splitting to Series h
h = df['Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int).rename('hour')
#for groupby use instead column Series
grouped_count = df.groupby([h, 'Type'])['Time'].count().to_frame()
#divide by aggregate first level hour and sum
grouped_count['Fraction'] =  grouped_count.div(grouped_count.sum(level=0))
print(grouped_count)
           Time  Fraction
hour Type                
1    foo      2      1.00
9    bar      1      0.25
     foo      3      0.75
11   bar      1      1.00
15   bar      1      0.50
     foo      1      0.50
21   foo      1      1.00
```